# Making a navigation bar that includes a search bar

Tags: html, css, navbar

I'm working on a navigation bar for my website, and I want to add a search box to it. I'm using a text-field, and I've positioned it with CSS so that it's aligned perfectly, except depending on the resolution, it shifts around. How can I make sure it stays in one position? For reference, it's kind of like on Apple's website except bigger.

Here's my Code (note that the navlinks aren't lined up either so the #navlink section isn't really relevant:

```css
div#adholder
{
    width:728px;
    height:90px;
    align:center;
}

ul#navlinks
{
    postition: absolute;
    right: 280px;
    margin:20px;
    padding:0;
    list-style:none;
    width:525px;
}

#searchBox
{
    position: fixed;
    left: 890px;
    top: 250px;
    height: 30px;
}
/*#searchBox
{
    position:absolute;
    right:150;
    top:150;
    width: 300px;
    height: 35px;
}*/

#submitButton
{
    display: none;
}
ul#navlinks li
{
    display: inline;
}

ul#navlinks li a
{
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 5px 0;
    width:100px;
    background: none;
    color:#000;
    float:left;
}
```

```html
<img id="navbar" src="images/Navbar.png" alt="Navigation"/>
<form method="get" action="" class="search">
    <input class="msb" maxlength="2048" id="searchBox" size="40" title="Search" value="" lang="en" />
    <input value="Search" id="submitButton" type="submit" />
</form>
<ul id="navlinks">
    <li id="navHome"><a href="index.php">Home</a></li>
    <li id="navSubmit"><a href="submit.html">Submit</a></li>
    <li id="navArchive"><a href="archive.html">Archive</a></li>
    <li id="navApps"><a href="apps.html">Apps</a></li>
    <li id="navContact"><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
</ul>
```

(For some reason the code formatter isn't working...)

This is how it looks on my 1366x768 laptop screen:
[image: This is how it looks on my 1366x768 laptop screen.]

Comment: What do you have so far?

Comment: This sounds like a CSS issue. Please post a snippet of your code (relevant HTML and CSS), right now we can't help you fix your layout.

Answer (score -1):

use `position:absolute;` and set all four parameter `top: bottom: right: left:` in style

Answer (score -1):

Maybe should use **percentage** instead of px. It will adapt according to resolution. And if you want to optimize your page for all resolutions you should use ***media query***. For ex. navlinks should have max-width 70% and float left and searchbar max-width 30% and fliat right. Or modern approach is to use ***display: flex*** for outter div.